# What are the rules for Pkunk ship regeneration/resurrection?

Tags: star-control-2

Pkunk ships seem to have the ability to regenerate/resurrect if killed in battle.

However, it seems pretty random when they do or don't regenerate.

Are there specific known rules for when regeneration does/doesn't happen?

Comment: BTW, reseaching this I run into all sorts of contradictory claims. From "always 50% chance, no factors" to "factors involving whether you are firing, what evergy level, planet collisions".

Comment: As an FYI - since SC2 code is now open source, the question is 100% canonically answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging through the available source code (or at least the git repository debian uses to maintain this package) I tracked the effect down to the following code snippet in `ships/pkunk/pkunk.c`, in the function `pkunk_preprocess()`:

```
        if (((BYTE)TFB_Random () & 1)
                        && (hPhoenix = AllocElement ()))
        {

                LockElement (hPhoenix, &PhoenixPtr);
                PhoenixPtr->state_flags =
                                FINITE_LIFE | NONSOLID | IGNORE_SIMILAR
                                | (ElementPtr->state_flags & (GOOD_GUY | BAD_GUY));
                PhoenixPtr->life_span = 1;

                PhoenixPtr->death_func = intercept_pkunk_death;

                SetElementStarShip (PhoenixPtr, StarShipPtr);

                UnlockElement (hPhoenix);
                InsertElement (hPhoenix, GetHeadElement ());
        }
```

If I've interpreted this right, what happens is that the resurrection is predetermined when the ship is spawned -- if TFB_Random() returns an odd value, the death_func() call is replaced with intercept_pkunk_death() which is defined a little further down in the code and triggers the "HAAAAAllelujah!" reincarnation before spawning a new Pkunk ship -- which itself calls pkunk_preprocess() and continues the cycle.

TL;DR: According to at least the source code as it exists in Debian, the odds of a respawn are as close to 50% as a software random generator can get.

(No, I don't think other versions behave wildly differently, but this is the only version I can be absolutely certain about; if you want to know for sure whether your version is the same, check the source code for the function described above)

**EDIT** Whoops, spoke slightly too soon.

In the function `intercept_pkunk_death()`:

```
        if (GRAVITY_MASS (ShipPtr->mass_points + 1))
        {
                ElementPtr->state_flags |= DISAPPEARING;
                ElementPtr->life_span = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                ShipPtr->mass_points = MAX_SHIP_MASS + 1;
                StarShipPtr->RaceDescPtr->preprocess_func = ShipPtr->preprocess_func;
                StarShipPtr->RaceDescPtr->postprocess_func = ShipPtr->postprocess_func;
                StarShipPtr->RaceDescPtr->init_weapon_func =
                                (COUNT (*) (PELEMENT ElementPtr,
                                                HELEMENT Weapon[]))
                                                ShipPtr->death_func;

                ElementPtr->death_func = new_pkunk;
        }
```

`GRAVITY_MASS()` is a defined function that tests whether a value's mass is higher than `MAX_SHIP_MASS` * 10 (which in turn is a defined value of 10).

So there *is* another nondeterministic factor that can determine whether the reincarnation is called off, involving the ship's mass_points. It's a little harder to figure out how those are calculated, but Pkunk ships start off at a mass of '1' and this check doesn't trip unless mass_points are higher than 100...

Comment: Line 230 sets mass_points to 1, and line 302 sets mass_points to 11, so those won't result in GRAVITY_MASS(...) returning true.  But line 413 sets mass_points to "(BYTE)angle", which in theory could be greater than 100, but I don't know if it's possible based on the program logic.  Someone else looked at the mass_points and said [it is irrelevant to the regeneration](http://forum.uqm.stack.nl/index.php?topic=1299.15), but I'm not sure if he's correct.

Comment: I also found a [version of the source](https://code.google.com/p/uqm-hd/source/browse/branches/uqm-import/sc2/src/uqm/ships/pkunk/pkunk.c?spec=svn403&r=403) with someone's comments added, and one comment says "GRAVITY_MASS() indicates a warp-out here. If Pkunk dies while warping out, there is no reincarnation."  If that is true, then mass_points are irrelevant, although that version of the source does have a few modifications from the original source (not sure if gameplay was affected at all), so there's a chance the comment isn't valid for the original source.